# Making an error message for the repeating in or out if loops in the database table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, arduino-uno, rfid

Good Day, to make things clear I will introduce my ongoing system which is "Gate attendance for student in our university", this system is consists of RFID reader RC522 and Arduino, the student should tap his/her RFID tag and the data retrieved shown at the monitor.. The system is our capstone project and it is done but the panel required us for another problem to be solved.

All functions is already done about the scanning,retrieving data,registering students , this will apply to the college students which is feel free to go out and in anytime depends on the schedule unlike highschool just one IN and OUT.

The two RFID reader is placed in Entrance and Exit of the University theres a system for out in the exit and In for the entrance.The data retrieved from in and out would save into the same table. 
How can I show the messagebox warning to the students if he taps IN without go OUT first? I know it something about the query. but I have no Idea. I need some help here for my Capstone.. Any Comments and suggestion is appreciated advance.. Here is my code about the retrieving the data based on the RFID tag number shown in the textbox changed event..by the way my table studlogs is the one handled the attendance.

```
Private Sub studtag_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles studtag.TextChanged

    Notenrolled.Close()
    greet.Text = ""
    PictureBox4.Visible = False

    If studtag.Text = "44F2F38B" Then

        Endday()

    End If


    If studtag.Text = recents.Text Then

        Alreadylogin.Show()
    ElseIf studtag.TextLength = 8 Then

        DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(6), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
        con = New MySqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dat"
        Dim query As String

        query = "select * from dat.students"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)

        Dim table As New DataTable

        Try
            con.Open()
            'Gets or sets an SQL statement or stored procedure used to select records in the database.
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = "SELECT * from students where `studtags`='" & studtag.Text & "';"
            End With
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(table)
            'it gets the data from specific column and fill it into Label

            idno.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(1)
            lastxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(2)
            firstxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(3)
            middletxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(4)
            dob.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(6)
            year.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(7)
            crsetxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(10)

            tagtxt.Text = studtag.Text
            timein.Text = times.Text

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dr.Read()

            If dob.Text = bday.Text Then
                greet.Text = firstxt.Text + " Today is your Birthday. Greetings :D."
                PictureBox4.Visible = True

            End If

            Dim img() As Byte = CType(dr("studpic"), Byte())


            Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(img)
                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

            End Using
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\BOR\Desktop\Parsu Gate\Parsu\audio\scanned.wav")
            insert()
            loadtable()
            studdailyhistory()


        Catch ex As Exception
            Notenrolled.Show()
            DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(5), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
            If studtag.Text = "44F2F38B" Then
                Notenrolled.Close()
            End If


        Finally

            con.Dispose()
            con.Close()

        End Try

    End If
    recents.Text = tagtxt.Text



End Sub

Public Sub insert()

    con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dat"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

    Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
    mstream.Close()

    Try

        con.Open()
        Dim query3 As String

        query3 = "insert into dat.studlogs (studtags,idno,lastxt,firstxt,middletxt,dob,log,timein,crse,studpic) values ('" & tagtxt.Text & "','" & idno.Text & "','" & lastxt.Text & "','" & firstxt.Text & "','" & middletxt.Text & "','" & dob.Text & "','" & log.Text & "','" & timein.Text & "','" & crsetxt.Text & "',@studpic)"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query3, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studpic", arrImage)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader


        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub


Public Sub studdailyhistory()

    con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dat"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

    Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
    mstream.Close()

    Try

        con.Open()
        Dim query3 As String

        query3 = "insert into dat.studdailyhistory (studtags,idno,lastxt,firstxt,middletxt,dob,log,timein,crse,dates,studpic) values ('" & tagtxt.Text & "','" & idno.Text & "','" & lastxt.Text & "','" & firstxt.Text & "','" & middletxt.Text & "','" & dob.Text & "','" & log.Text & "','" & timein.Text & "','" & crsetxt.Text & "','" & wholedate.Text & "',@studpic)"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query3, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studpic", arrImage)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub loadtable()

    con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dat"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataset As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    Try

        con.Open()
        Dim query3 As String

        query3 = "select idno as 'Student_ID',lastxt as 'LastName',firstxt as 'FirstName',middletxt as 'MiddleName',log as 'Status',timein as 'Timein',crse as 'Course' from dat.studlogs"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query3, con)
        SDA.SelectCommand = cmd
        SDA.Fill(dbDataset)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataset
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataset)

        DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(5), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)

        If dbDataset.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            logins.Text = dbDataset.Rows.Count.ToString()
        End If

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understand properly, but i guess u dont want the student be able to clock in twice without clock out. 
You have multiple options. 
The simpliest, you can use a status field in your db. When student clock in then save "status"=1 (student onsite), and at clockout "status"=0 (student not onsite). At every clock in and clock out you check the status of student. If 1 then can't clock in again as she/he onsite already.
Or you save in the log when they tap the fob it was an entrance or leave and when you query the table with student you order the table by last insert time so the last record will come up where you see the last status of the log.

**Edit**:
Add an extra bool type column in your database to students table like "studOnsite" and set the default value 0.  When a student scan a card and you get the student details from the table here :

```
.CommandText = "SELECT * from students where `studtags`='" & studtag.Text & "';"
```

You will get back the "studOnsite" column aswell. After you can simply check the value like :

```
if (table.Rows(0).Item("studOnsite") then 
   'student already onsite so she/he is leaving
   greet.Text = firstxt.Text & "Good bye!"
   'update the student table and change "studOnsite" to false
   'dim query as string=string.format("UPDATE students SET studOnsite=false WHERE studtags='{0}'",studtag.Text)
else 
   'student wasn't onsite so she/he is just arrived
   greet.Text = firstxt.Text & "Welcome back!"
   'update the student table and change "studOnsite" to true as student is onsite now
   'dim query as string=string.format("UPDATE students SET studOnsite=true WHERE studtags='{0}'",studtag.Text)
end if
```

Comment: Thank you fra I will try that suggestion ..can I use if status = "IN" then show message?...but do you know sir how to check inside the database because that statement will only check the interface labels and textboxes.? Not in the table

Comment: see my edited answer pls!

Comment: Thanks fra many thanks to you..there is no Boolean data type in mysql workbench ? can i Use TINYINT? and default 0?

Comment: yes you can use which ever you wish. Every number format will do. They all can be true or false as they are equivalent of 1 and 0. True=1 and False=0.

Comment: Thank you so much fra for paying much attention to my problem...you point out what I wanted to happen...I will work it out now.